# Async read from UdpSocket

Tags: asynchronous, concurrency, rust, future, rust-tokio

I am trying to concurrently process arriving UDP packets in Tokio. However the following MWE does not do what I expected:

```
extern crate futures;
extern crate tokio_core;
extern crate tokio_io;

use futures::{Future, Stream};
use std::net::SocketAddr;
use tokio_core::net::{UdpCodec, UdpSocket};
use tokio_core::reactor::Core;

// just a codec to send and receive bytes
pub struct LineCodec;
impl UdpCodec for LineCodec {
    type In = (SocketAddr, Vec<u8>);
    type Out = (SocketAddr, Vec<u8>);

    fn decode(&mut self, addr: &SocketAddr, buf: &[u8]) -> std::io::Result<Self::In> {
        Ok((*addr, buf.to_vec()))
    }

    fn encode(&mut self, (addr, buf): Self::Out, into: &mut Vec<u8>) -> SocketAddr {
        into.extend(buf);
        addr
    }
}

fn compute(addr: SocketAddr, msg: Vec<u8>) -> Box<Future<Item = (), Error = ()>> {
    println!("Starting to compute for: {}", addr);
    // sleep is a placeholder for a long computation
    std::thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_secs(8));
    println!("Done computing for for: {}", addr);
    Box::new(futures::future::ok(()))
}

fn main() {
    let mut core = Core::new().unwrap();
    let handle = core.handle();
    let listening_addr = "127.0.0.1:8080".parse::<SocketAddr>().unwrap();
    let socket = UdpSocket::bind(&listening_addr, &handle).unwrap();
    println!("Listening on: {}", socket.local_addr().unwrap());

    let (writer, reader) = socket.framed(LineCodec).split();

    let socket_read = reader.for_each(|(addr, msg)| {
        println!("Got {:?}", msg);
        handle.spawn(compute(addr, msg));
        Ok(())
    });

    core.run(socket_read).unwrap();
}
```

Connecting two terminals with `$ nc -u localhost 8080` and sending some text, I can see that the message from the second terminal is processed after the first finished.

What do I have to change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Stefan said in another answer, you should not block in the asynchronous code. Given your example, it looks like the `sleep` is a placeholder for some long computation. So instead of using a timeout, you should delegate that computation to another thread like [this example](https://tokio.rs/docs/getting-started/futures/#asynchronous-version):

```
extern crate futures;
extern crate futures_cpupool;

use futures::Future;
use futures_cpupool::CpuPool;

...

let pool = CpuPool::new_num_cpus();

...

fn compute(handle: &Handle, addr: SocketAddr, _msg: Vec<u8>) -> Box<Future<Item = (), Error = ()>> {
    // I don't know enough about Tokio to know how to make `pool` available here
    pool.spawn_fn (|| {
        println!("Starting to compute for: {}", addr);
        std::thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_secs(8));
        println!("Done computing for for: {}", addr);
        Ok(())
    })
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant. I made a comment to my question to clarify the use of sleep.

Answer (score 2):

Never `sleep` in async code (and avoid any other blocking calls too).

You might want to use [`Timeout`](https://docs.rs/tokio-core/0.1.12/tokio_core/reactor/struct.Timeout.html) instead like this:

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=9d95d98f4419f8dedac51b0e101121f3&version=stable)

```
fn compute(handle: &Handle, addr: SocketAddr, _msg: Vec<u8>) -> Box<Future<Item = (), Error = ()>> {
    println!("Starting to compute for: {}", addr);
    Box::new(
        Timeout::new(std::time::Duration::from_secs(8), handle)
            .unwrap()
            .map_err(|e| panic!("timeout failed: {:?}", e))
            .and_then(move |()| {
                println!("Done computing for for: {}", addr);
                Ok(())
            }),
    )
}
```